# Cannot create a Zend Framework Project in Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, project

I am pretty new to netbeans (former zend studio and eclipse user) and also new to zend framework. For a few hours now I am trying to set up a new zend framework project in netbeans on my windows 7 machine. I downloaded zf, added the library path to the include path in php.ini and configured the things in the options dialog of netbeans (php->zend). the first thing i don't understand, if I enter the path to the zend script zf.bat and afterwards click the Search... button, it says that there are no zend scripts found. Although, I can then register the provider without getting any errors. 
If I then create a new project and select the zend framework checkbox it takes a little while and ends up in an error message "Zend project not created! (verify zend script in tools > options > PHP > Zend or review IDE log).
The IDE log tells the same again, unfortunately no new information.

Can anyone help me? I have no idea whats wrong...

Environment: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 on windows 7 (64 bit), zf 1.10.8, pear installed, netbeans (php) 6.9.1

THANKS!

Comment: Might want to ask on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Does `zf.bat` run as expected from command line? Netbeans is just a wrapper for this.

Comment: Pretty sure you should add the zf path to the windows PATH to.

Comment: It sounds likely that you haven't added your PHP.exe folder to your Windows PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's me again. In the meantime i discovered the reason for my problem. For all windows users, if you have enabled the UAC (which is enabled by default) you should run your Netbeans as Administrator! Unfortunately, no error message indicates this issue.
But anyway, thanks for the comments, they were useful too! bye...